# Making CodeBlocks work with Terminator?

Tags: ubuntu, ide, compiler

I want to make the programs compiled by Codeblocks, run the shell program 'Terminator'.

So I went into Environment Settings > Terminal to launch console programs, the default value is `xterm -T $TITLE -e` so I replaced it with `/usr/bin/terminator -T $TITLE -e` but when I compile the program doesn't run...

How can I do it?

Comment: You're sure the program is at /usr/bin and not somewhere else like /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Yes I am sure that is the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I just added in Codeblocks:

```
terminator -T $TITLE -x´
```

and Terminator seems to work fine.

Just use `-x` instead of `-e`

Answer (score 0):

One of the pitfalls in using Terminator (or any of the VTE-wrappers) is that the interpretation of the **`-e`** option is incompatible with xterm and rxvt if you happen to have more than one token/word in the command to execute.  The VTE-wrappers expect only **one** token, while xterm and rxvt use all of the tokens after **`-e`**.  Depending on the command, Terminator will indeed not work.

Further reading:

- [Terminator - Multiple GNOME terminals in one window](https://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator)
- [**`-e`** *program [ arguments ... ]*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-e) (xterm manual)